# Insert a Shortcode in Wordpress Admin

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, shortcode

I installed a whatsapp chat plugin for wordpress where this one is displayed on the frontend perfectly.

I would like this chat to appear on the **backend** pages. The plugin has a shortcode like this: **[njwa_button id = "1044"]**

It's possible? If possible how could I insert the shortcode into the functions.php file. I was able to insert a different chat using the function **add_action 'admin_footer'**

I tried something like this plus the chat button does not appear:

```
function custom_function_for_your_page() {
// put your php code here
<?php echo do_shortcode(“[njwa_button id="1044"]”); ?>
}
add_shortcode( 'njwa_button', 'custom_function_for_your_page' );
add_action( 'admin_footer', 'custom_function_for_your_page' ); // For back-end
```

Comment: didn't you pose this question a couple days ago? the code you show is a bit strange, you are doing add_shortcode and calling the very same shortcode in the function.  probably you'll have to analyze plugin, call the main function manually and enqueue scripts and css yourself.  i guess the plugin enqueues them only in frontend hooks. which plugin is it?

Comment: Why is there a **<?php ... ?>** inside of a **php** function? Why do you call the shortcode in itself? Not all plugins are able to work on front- AND backend of WordPress, so you may have to either work more with it or just ditch it for another one.

Comment: I'm using the WhatsApp plugin For Wordpress: https://ninjateam.org/wordpress-whatsapp-chat-tutorial/

Comment: I do not understand anything about .php. I just found that by being a shortcode it was just calling some wordpress functions.